# How to transfer env.host to fabric when using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, fabric

I have hundreds of box can be accessed only with different gateway, like below shows:

```
gateway1:ip1,ip2
gateway2:ip3,ip4 ...
```

All job need done in one minute, so I use multiprocess below command `fab -f  ytj_sto.py doitnow`, errors below.

```
[]
None
None
***Warning*** Host None via ssh is down
```

Code:

```
@parallel(pool_size=20)
def coll():
    print env.hosts
    print env.host
    print env.gateway
    if _is_ssh_ok(env.host):
        d = patt()

def doitnow():
    p=Pool(20)
    with open('ytj_sto.hn','r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            if not len(line) or line.startswith('#'):
                continue
            env.gateway = line.split(':')[0]
            env.hosts = line.split(':')[1].split(',')
            result = p.apply_async(coll, args=())
            result.get()
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

EDITED:
     I have used fab -H -g solved the issue,thanks all

```
  def fabfun(Hosts,Gate,des,func1):
        with settings(hide('running'), warn_only=True):
           local(("fab -H %s -g %s -f %s %s ") % (Hosts,Gate,des,func1))

p=Pool(20)
starttime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
print('Waiting for all job done...%s' % starttime)
with open('ytj_sto.hn','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if not len(line) or line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        Hosts = line.split(':')[1]
        Gate = line.split(':')[0]
        p.apply_async(fabfun, args=(Hosts,Gate,des,func1))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Where is the fabric task (`patt`) you are trying to call?  And how did you implement `_is_ssh_ok`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set env variables dynamically like you are, you should use `execute`.  That way the `execute`d task takes on the `env` values that you set at runtime.  But unfortunately, because `fabric` is not fully thread-safe, you can only kick off tasks like this in parallel in your situation once per gateway because `env` is a global singleton.

> A simple but integral aspect of Fabric is what is known as the
>   “environment”: a Python dictionary subclass, which is used as a
>   combination settings registry and shared inter-task data namespace.
>
> The environment dict is currently implemented as a global singleton,
>   fabric.state.env, and is included in fabric.api for convenience. Keys
>   in env are sometimes referred to as “env variables”.

```
from fabric.context_managers import env

@parallel(pool_size=20)
def check_and_patt():
    if _is_ssh_ok(env.host):
        d = patt()

def doitnow():
    p=Pool(20)
    with open('ytj_sto.hn','r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            if not len(line) or line.startswith('#'):
                continue
            env.gateway = line.split(':')[0]
            env.hosts = line.split(':')[1].split(',')
            result = execute(check_and_patt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just supply `env` to the `coll` function as a parameter, like so:

```
@parallel(pool_size=20)
def coll(env): # <-- updated
    print env.hosts
    print env.host
    print env.gateway
    if _is_ssh_ok(env.host):
        d = patt()

def doitnow():
    p=Pool(20)
    with open('ytj_sto.hn','r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            if not len(line) or line.startswith('#'):
                continue
            env.gateway = line.split(':')[0]
            env.hosts = line.split(':')[1].split(',')
            result = p.apply_async(coll, args=(env,)) # <-- updated
            result.get()
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

There's a few quirks to using the [multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming). This info might be especially relevant to you scenario:

> Global variables
>
> Bear in mind that if code run in a child process tries to access a global variable, then the value it sees (if any) may not be the same as the value in the parent process at the time that Process.start was called.
>
> However, global variables which are just module level constants cause no problems.